# Google Calendar events showing on iphone but not Google Calendar

Tags: iphone, google-calendar-api, facebook-events

I used the freeware php script from this [tutorial](http://boldmove.co/tutorials/how-to-sync-facebook-page-events-with-google-calendar/) , which I host on my own website to sync Facebook events with my Google Calendar.

Everything works correctly as the Facebook events appear on my iphone calendar: [image]

but weirdly the imported FB events don't appear on my actual Google Calendar (or the Calendars+ app I use on my iphone...)

Any ideas?